# Sequelize one to many and display

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, relational-database

I am new in the relational database. I am using node js and express for the backend, REST API and database is Postgresql. I am using Sequelize for connection and models.I have created two models, one is a student and another is a course. My goal is One student can have multiple courses and want to prevent duplicate student name, phone, email. I successfully connect to the database and able to post,get,update, delete the both student and course model. From testing the app I am using Postman. But I am not sure, am I doing right for the relationship between student and course. And also I don't how to display the relationship between two tables. I will be really glad if anyone helps me out.

I want to display my like this:

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Anni Anonen",
      "birthday": "1992-02-28",
      "address": "Kivakatu 1",
      "zipcode": "00500",
      "city": "Helsinki",
      "phone": "+358506760702",
      "email": "anni.anonen@testing.fi",
      "courses": [1,2,3] //SHOW COURSES LIKE THIS
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Ville Anonen",
      "birthday": "2000-03-28",
      "address": "Hämeentie 1",
      "zipcode": "00510",
      "city": "Helsinki",
      "phone": "+358508660702",
      "email": "ville.anonen@testing.fi",
      "courses": [3]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Tapani Kumpu",
      "birthday": "1999-05-28",
      "address": "Jokukatu 17",
      "zipcode": "00560",
      "city": "Helsinki",
      "phone": "+358502330702",
      "email": "tapani.kumpu@testing.fi",
      "courses": [1,4]
    }

  ],
  "courses": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Gymnastics 1",
      "startdate": "2020-01-01",
      "enddate": "2020-02-10"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Gymnastics 2",
      "startdate": "2020-01-01",
      "enddate": "2020-02-10"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Fitness 1",
      "startdate": "2020-02-01",
      "enddate": "2020-02-20"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Dance 1",
      "startdate": "2020-05-01",
      "enddate": "2020-05-02"
    }
  ]
}
```

**This is my models**

```
const sequelize = require("sequelize");

var con = new sequelize("school", "postgres", "password", {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "postgres",

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

const Student = con.define("student", {
  name: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  birthday: {
    type: sequelize.DATEONLY,
    allowNull: false
  },
  address: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  zipcode: {
    type: sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
  },
  city: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  phone: {
    type: sequelize.BIGINT,
    allowNull: false
  },

  email: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      isEmail: true
    }
  }
});

const Course = con.define("course", {
  id: {
    type: sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: { type: sequelize.STRING },
  startdate: { type: sequelize.DATEONLY },
  enddate: { type: sequelize.DATEONLY },
  studentId: { type: sequelize.INTEGER, foreignKey: true }
});

Student.hasMany(Course);
Course.belongsTo(Student);

//con.sync({ force: true });

module.exports = { Student, Course };
```

**This is express server**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require("morgan");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const cors = require("cors");

const { Student, Course } = require("./db");
//app middlewear

app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); //body Parser

//student

app.get("/students", async (req, res, next) => { 
  try {
    await Student.findAll().then(docs => {
      const response = {
        count: docs.length,
        students: docs
      };
      res.json(response);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.get("/students/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    Student.findByPk(id).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      res.json(data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.put("/students/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const update = req.body;
  try {
    await Student.update(update, { where: { id } }).then(data => {
      res.json(data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.delete("/students/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  try {
    Student.destroy({ where: { id } }).then(data => {
      res.json(data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.post("/students", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const logs = new Student(req.body);
    const entry = await logs.save();
    res.json(entry);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.name === "ValidationError") {
      res.status(422);
    }
    next(error);
  }
});

//course

app.get("/courses", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await Course.findAll().then(docs => {
      const response = {
        count: docs.length,
        courses: docs
      };
      res.json(response);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.get("/courses/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    Course.findByPk(id).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      res.json(data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.put("/courses/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const update = req.body;
  try {
    await Course.update(update, { where: { id } }).then(data => {
      res.json(data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.delete("/courses/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  try {
    Course.destroy({ where: { id } }).then(data => {
      res.json(data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.post("/courses", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const logs = new Course(req.body);
    const entry = await logs.save();
    res.json(entry);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.name === "ValidationError") {
      res.status(422);
    }
    next(error);
  }
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(` App is listening at port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: Hmmm... Shoudn't it be a many to many relations ? Courses has many students, and student has many courses ?

Comment: How should I do it? I am really new in this field.

Comment: https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html